# Нужна ли запятая после слова "просьба"?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после слова "просьба". Например, "просьба отправить Ваше резюме по адресу..."

Answer (score 4):

Запятая не нужна. Просьба какая? отправлять. Хотя правильнее было бы сказать 'просим отправлять'.

Comment: получается несогласованное определение, которое обычно выделяется запятыми. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: не могу представить обособленное  инфинитивное определение. Да и другие тоже. Платье в горошек. Обособляется ряд однородных определении.

Answer (score 4):

Фраза стилистически сомнительна, отсюда расхождение в синтаксическом анализе - и, как следствие, пунктуации.

Варианты:
~1. "Просьба" использовано здесь как сокращение от "у нас есть/будет просьба: отправить резюме...". Тогда логично сохранить двоеточие, или, по современной практике, заменить его на тире.
~2. "Просьба" использовано само по себе как главный член (или его составляющая) номинативного предложения. Тогда никаких запятых. Этот случай разобран в других ответах.
~3. "Просьба" является заменой "пожалуйста" (стилистически неверной, но любимой бюрократами). Тогда оно является вводным и обособляется запятыми.

Самый разумный выход - заменить конструкцию на любой из предлагаемых вариантов ("будет просьба", "просим/предлагаем", "пожалуйста, вышлите" - и т.д. А если невозможно технически, то лучше, конечно, без знака.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужна. Нет оснований для постановки запятой.

Comment: получается несогласованное определение, которое обычно выделяется запятыми. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: (Есть) (что?) Просьба (какая?) отправить... Здесь слово "просьба" — подлежащее.

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже кажется, что после слова "просьба" уместно двоеточие, поскольку дальше идет раскрытие содержания просьбы.

Comment: Как вариант. Но не уверен, что лучший из возможных.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не нужна запятая. Также не нужно ставить и двоеточие. Данная фраза - деловой штамп. Подобные фразы используются исключительно в формализованной деловой переписке.

При этом само слово "просьба" использовано в качестве проявления вежливости в данной фразе. Если вдуматься в суть фразы, то *вас просят отправить ваше резюме по адресу*, но *вы не обязаны это делать*. В то же время, если слово "просьба" выделить запятой либо иным знаком препинания, фраза станет императивом.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, надо ставить запятую! Как вводное слово, подменяющее другое вводное слово «пожалуйста»!

Comment: «Пожалуйста» можно поставить перед «отправить»?